# Fast Pixels Access opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

i use this code to convert image to matrix ,so someone have any idea how can i convert this matrix to 1D one -->vector
 i want to have image data as a 1D array ,in row major order that is all pixel values in the first row are listed first ,followed by pixel values in the second row and so on.

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage( "lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3 );

cvConvert( img, mat );

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

{

for(int j=0;j<10;j++){


CvScalar scal = cvGet2D( mat,j,i);

printf( "(%.f,%.f,%.f) ",scal.val[0], scal.val[1], scal.val[2] );}


printf("\n");}



cvNamedWindow("une_window");
cvShowImage("une_window", img);

cvWaitKey();

cvDestroyWindow("une_window");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the C++ API:

```c
   cv::Mat img = cv::imread("a.jpg");

   std::vector<uchar> pixels;
   pixels.reserve(img.rows * img.cols * 3);

   if(img.isContinuous()) {
     pixels = std::vector<uchar>(img.ptr(0), img.ptr(0) + img.rows * img.cols * 3 );
   }
   else {
     for(int i = 0; i != img.rows; ++i) {
       uchar* p = img.ptr(i);
       for(int j = 0; j != img.cols * 3; ++j) {
         pixels.push_back(p[j]);
       }
     }   
   }
```

Comment: @Butterflay that indicates a linker error. At first you should set up your environment so that you can compile a minimal C++ opencv program.

Comment: In fact this is a one-liner! std::copy(img.begin(), img.end(), vector.begin());

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fastest way for continuous Mats is to use the reshape command:

```
Mat colVec = img.reshape(1, img.rows*img.cols); // change to a Nx3 column vector
```

The reshape command just changes the header, so it does not require pixel access and therefore runs in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should observe from video decoder output to know the video size information, other information collected from metadata in container parser might be not so accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ this is actually a one-liner:

```
cv::Mat_<float> img = cv::imread("a.jpg", 1);
std::vector<float> dest;
std::copy(img.begin(), img.end(), dest.begin());
```